# GoLang and Vue Project /Validate CORSE Error

Tags: go, go-gin

Me and my team are working on a project which uses golang at backend with gin,gorm,jwt,crypto frameworks and vue as front-end. We created a token validation system using jwt. Here is our user controller file content with login,signin and validate methods:

```
package Controllers



type BodyS struct {
    Username string
    Mail     string
    Password string
    Dropdown int
}
type BodyL struct {
    Mail     string
    Password string
}

func Signup(c *gin.Context) {
    var body BodyS
    var mentor Models.Mentor
    var company Models.Company

    if c.BindJSON(&body) != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "data err",
        })
        return
    }

    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(body.Password), 10)

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "password err",
        })
        return
    }

    var user Models.User

    user.Mail = body.Mail
    user.Password = string(hash)
    user.UserName = body.Username
    res := Config.DB.Create(&user)

    if res.Error != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "user err",
        })
        return
    }

    if body.Dropdown == 1 {
        mentor.UserID = user.ID
        //mentor.IsIndividual = true
        mentor.CompanyID = 3
        Config.DB.Create(&mentor)
        c.JSON(202, mentor)
        c.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "/MentorPage")

    }
    if body.Dropdown == 2 {
        company.UserID = user.ID
        Config.DB.Create(&company)
        c.JSON(202, "şirket olarak kaydınız yapıldı")
        c.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "/CompanyPage")

    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{})
}

func Login(c *gin.Context) {
    //enableCors(&w)
    var body BodyL
    var rol string
    var mentor Models.Mentor
    var mentee Models.Mentee
    var company Models.Company
    if c.Bind(&body) != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "data err",
        })
        return
    }

    var user Models.User
    Config.DB.First(&user, "mail = ?", body.Mail)
    fmt.Println(user.Mail)
    if user.ID == 0 {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "user err",
        })
        return
    }
    erro := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(body.Password))

    if erro != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "password err",
        })
        return
    }
    Config.DB.First(&mentor, "user_id = ?", user.ID)
    Config.DB.First(&mentee, "user_id = ?", user.ID)
    Config.DB.First(&company, "user_id = ?", user.ID)

    if mentor.ID != 0 {
        rol = "mentor"
    }
    if mentee.ID != 0 {
        rol = "mentee"
    }
    if company.ID != 0 {
        rol = "company"
    }
    if mentor.ID == 0 && mentee.ID == 0 && company.ID == 0 {
        rol = "user"
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "sub":  user.ID,
        "rol":  rol,
        "mail": user.Mail,
        "exp":  time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix(),
    })
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")))
    fmt.Println(tokenString)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "ERROR": "token err",
        })
        return
    }
    c.SetSameSite(http.SameSiteLaxMode)
    c.SetCookie("Authorization", tokenString, 3600*24, "", "", false, true)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "token": tokenString,
    })

}

func Validate(c *gin.Context) {
    user, _ := c.Get("user")
    //un := user.(Models.User).UserName
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": user,
    })
}
```

We are using  a middle ware:

```
func RequireAuth(c *gin.Context) {
    tokenString, err := c.Cookie("Authorization")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR1")
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }

    token, _ := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Poşet giriş beklenmemişti: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }
        return []byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")), nil
    })
    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
        if float64(time.Now().Unix()) > claims["exp"].(float64) {
            fmt.Println("Error3")
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
        var user Models.User
        Config.DB.First(&user, claims["sub"])
        if user.ID == 0 {
            fmt.Println("ERROR2")
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
        c.Set("user", user)
        c.Next()

    } else {
        fmt.Println("ERROR4")
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }

}
```

And those are our routes:

```
func UserRoute(router *gin.Engine) {
   router.POST("/Signup", Controllers.Signup)
   router.POST("/Login", Controllers.Login)
   router.GET("/Validate", middleware.RequireAuth, Controllers.Validate)
   router.POST("/Logout", Controllers.Logout)

}
```

We call our routes in the main like this:

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    Config.Connect()
    Routes.UserRoute(router)
    router.Run(":8080")

}
```

When we call login method from the front end part by clicking login button like this:
[image: Login Page]

We took corse error like in this picture:
[image: Frontend corse error]

And the out put in go like this:
[image: GO message]

How can we manage this cors error. We need help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You dont use any CORS settings as I see. Try this https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help, we already used " router.Use(cors.Default())" in the main.go, however it didn't work as well....

Comment: There is a place you put router.Use(cors) ? Also its a better way to apply middleware before any routes declared, at the group of routes. Like in this example https://go.dev/play/p/F6Mz4gPzTvC and here with cors https://go.dev/play/p/sEiKRH9tYzk

Comment: I guess we don't have, actually this topic is new for us so we couldn't understand how to add this into to our project. Can you suggest us something we can do?

Answer (score 0):

You need a CORS middleware, which handles OPTIONS requests and adds a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` heading to the response, which basically tells the browser that server allows to accept requests from another domain.

Overall it's a great tool to control who may send requests to your server, what this requests could be and where exactly from.

You can use something like https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors or just write your own middleware, it's not really that much code.

Also it's worth to mention, if your front is on example.com and your api is also located there, eg.: example.com/api – you won't need any CORS configuration on prod.

Comment: Hi,actually we are using this package which you shared but we are not sure whether we are using it right or not. we implement get method then add 'router.Use(cors.Default())
' to our main.go. isn't it enough it to work?

Comment: cors.Default() should be enough according to their readme. Just make sure you register cors middleware before routes. In addition to that you may check issues on their github: https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/issues/84